# How to prevent mobile Safari from closing the keyboard when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

I have an input field of type text and a submit button:

```
<input type="text">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

The Problem is that when the user presses the submit button on mobile Safari, the input is unfocused/blurred and the software keyboard disappears.

How do I make the input keep focus?

Just setting focus on the input when the button is pressed is no option because I only want to keep the keyboard open if it has been open before submit press. If the keyboard has been manually closed before pressing the button, I don't want it to open.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this. What is the use-case? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: @JBS When using the iMessage app on the iPhone this is exactly the behavior I want. If the user taps send while the keyboard is open, it stays open. When the keyboard is closed and send is pressed, it stays closed.